# JSON To Bean Definition

Tags: java, json, paypal

I am trying to map a PayPal API JSON response to a Java Bean.  I used a tool called http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ in order to create the object.

Has it done it correctly, based on the following JSON?   It created 5 different objects.

- DoReferenceTransactionResponseDetails.java
- FeeAmount.java
- GrossAmount.java
- PaymentInfo.java
- TaxAmount.java

I guess I need to include those in a base object called something like **RefTransactionResponse** that includes **Timestamp**, **ack**, etc?  Is the only other way to do this is using inner classes?

```
{ "doReferenceTransactionResponseDetails":{
     "billingAgreementID":"B-92T23517L08326025",
     "paymentInfo":{
        "transactionID":"4U482182NY9710827",
        "transactionType":"MERCHTPMT",
        "paymentType":"INSTANT",
        "paymentDate":"2013-09-05T14:36:35Z",
        "grossAmount":{
           "currencyID":"USD",
           "value":"14.99"
        },
        "feeAmount":{
           "currencyID":"USD",
           "value":"0.73"
        },
        "taxAmount":{
           "currencyID":"USD",
           "value":"0.00"
        },
        "paymentStatus":"COMPLETED",
        "pendingReason":"NONE",
        "reasonCode":"NONE",
        "protectionEligibility":"Ineligible",
        "protectionEligibilityType":"None"
     }
  },
  "timestamp":"2013-09-05T14:36:36Z",
  "ack":"SUCCESS",
  "correlationID":"11b0602aa6328",
  "errors":[

  ],
  "version":"106.0",
  "build":"7560199"
```

}

Comment: are you using their [sdk](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the API you used is reasonable, I would expect  DoReferenceTransactionResponseDetails.java to contain references to the other generated classes, as well as fields for timestamp, ack, correlationID, errors, version, and build.

There's no need to create inner classes, which may not be what you actually meant.